# Error "Modal no es una función" al llamar a una vista parcial

Tags: jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc

> Trabajo con ASP.NET MVC 5, Visual Studio Community Edition, jQuery v3.

Llamo a la vista parcial desde un botón en realidad un input.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createPartialView();" 
data-toggle="modal" value="Nuevo" data-target="#AgregarEmpleado" />
```

Implemente una función que llama a una vista parcial.

```
@section Scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function createPartialView() {
            var urlVista = "@Url.Action("Create", "Empleado")";
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                type: "GET",
                url: urlVista,
                data: {},
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#resultado').html(response);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
            });

            $("#AgregarEmpleado").modal("show");
        }
    </script>

}
```

_layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Nombre de la aplicación", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Acerca de", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacto", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Mi aplicación ASP.NET</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

El mensaje de error es el siguiente:

> Modal no es una función

Exactamente el error es en esta línea de código

```
$("#AgregarEmpleado").modal("show");
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Revisa la [documentación](https://jquerymodal.com/) probablemente te falta cargar el script del modal y, además, se debe mostrar con el elemento del modal, no con un botón: `$('#id-de-ventana-modal').modal('show');`

Comment: estás llamando ese script antes de que los que necesiten hayan cargado. Muestra lo que tienes en tu _layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Tenía la línea que llama al modal fuera del success

```
function createPartialView() {
        var urlVista = "@Url.Action("Create", "Empleado")";
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: urlVista,
            data: {},
            success: function (response) {
                $('#resultado').empty().html(response);
                $("#AgregarEmpleado").modal("show");
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```